# youtube video full on section

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have youtube video link

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zuQGx1H1Qh8?autoplay=1"  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

and I want to make it fullscreen of my section tag. I have added `width:100% height:100%` but result is:
[image]

other I have tried

```
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 100;
```

but same result. Any idea how i can solve that?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mwykdrn3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `padding: 60px;` and `padding-left: 120px;` from your section tag and It's solved

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

Remove the padding : http://jsfiddle.net/mwykdrn3/1/

```
section {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Solution #2**

Use absolute positioning http://jsfiddle.net/mwykdrn3/2/

```
#yvideo {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```